# Overloaded assignment operator is not getting called

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I have written a overloaded assignment operator of class `perform` copying all the variable values.
For ex :in Exp.cpp

```
class perform
{
    LOG *ptr;
int a;
//constructor
//destructor
perform operator=(const perform & rhs){

   ptr = rhs.ptr; a=rhs.s;
return * this;}
};
```

In another class `output`, I have declared a pointer for `abc`.

```
perform * ptr = StatCol::CreateCol(frm);
abc = ptr; //this line should invoke assignment overloaded.
           //but in my case it's not invoked.
```

Comment: Show us your actual code, including the declaration of `abc`. It's hard to know what is a mistake that's causing your problem, and what is a mistake you made retyping your code here.

Comment: code is sooo huge.
Or else you ask me the questions related.i will tell related to my problem.Here abc is pointer of type Perform.Wehter LHS can be pointer?

Answer (score 10):

Assuming abc is a Perform object, you need to dereference the pointer you are assigning:

```
abc = * ptr;
```

If abc itself is a pointer, then you can't do what you are asking - you can't overload assignment where the LHS is a pointer. You would have to dereference both pointers:

```
* abc = * ptr;
```

Comment: @Vishu Do what I said - dereference both pointers - this will use your assignment operator.

Comment: Please tell how?
am not getting.
what i want finnaly is abc(pointer of type Perform) should contained copied values.And it has to be pointer only.i canot change.In this case how do i ensure my  asigment operator is called

Comment: @Vishnu I've told you what to do - I don't see I can be any clearer.

Comment: Ok,LHS should not be pointer,then only my asigment operator is called is it?Thanks lot.will try and comment.thanks

Comment: perform& operator=(const perform & rhs);
Sorry this is actual line,i missed the referance symbol in the above .
In this case LHS can be pointer?Sorry if am wrong.

Comment: @Vishu You are wrong. The C++ language simply does not allow operator=() to be overloaded for assignment to pointers.

Comment: Thanks a lot.its working now.And thanks for the knowledge sharing

Answer (score 0):

Also, it is safer to return via reference thus avoiding a copy constructor being invoked.

```
    const perform& operator=(const perform & rhs){

     if (this != &rhs)
     {
       ptr = rhs.ptr; a=rhs.s;
     }
     return * this;
   }
```

Comment: yes i have written the same as aobve. But its not getting called.
LHS is a pointer.i.e abc is a pointer

Answer (score 0):

```
Custom assignment operator works only with user defined types so do like this:

perform p1,p2; 
p1 = p2;
perform *p = &p2;
p1 = *p;  


You can't override assignment of built in types(int , char etc.).

perform *p1,*p2; 
p1 = p2;

It simply copies the address of p2 to p1.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the sample code you are assigning pointers, so there is no chance you could ever call the assignment operator without dereferencing the pointer.

And using this design, the risk of doing shallow copy is huge. In addition the C++ assignment operator signature is: 'perform & operator = ( ... )' as stated in the standard. It must return a reference to the same object in order for the compiler to consider it as you expect.

[more about assignment operator...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_in_C%2B%2B).

Comment: The standard has no requirement on the return type, which never takes part in overloading.